# Sql Agent Jobs executes too slow

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have posted a question like this before but is seems that I did not explain the whole story clear. So I made this one to explain it in details. Here's the stored procedure

```
USE [xxxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MARK_ACTIVE]    Script Date: 4/20/2015 5:55:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxx]
AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
INSERT INTO [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]      (smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX)
SELECT TOP 3 smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX
FROM [098.765.4.321].[[DBASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2] cr
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  id,smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX          FROM [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]  c
  WHERE cr.smsdt = c.smsdt)
```

and here's my job settings

**My General**
[image]

**My Steps**
[image]

**My advance steps**
[image]

**My Scheduler**
[image]

When I run the stored proc it executes for less than 10 seconds but when i try to call that stored proc using the job this is what happen

[image]

it just keep on in progress state but nothing happens, looks like it got stuck in that state.

Comment: What are the waits associated - run sp_whoisactive while you run sql agent job ? May be blocking ? How big is the table ? Also, why are you using `TOP *` **without** `an order by`  clause  ?

Comment: How large is your `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` table?

Comment: Now it is not stuck in in progress....it shows `executed as user:NT service\sqlserveragent. login failed for user 'nt authority\anonymous logon'.[SQLSTATE 28000](Error 18456). The step Failed when using sql server agent`

Comment: Are you able to run other Agent Jobs or is it just this one that's bombing?

Comment: its the only one that having this error.

Comment: Sounds like the linked server in the statement is not properly setup for security or your SPNs are incorrect. I'm assuming it's the former rather than the latter. Double check the security settings for the linked server, the agent service account, and the destination to make sure they are all copacetic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Authentication in the linked server setup it will not work using the SQL Server agent even if you have Kerberos correctly setup. You can configure the linked server to use SQL authentication for those connections but I would recommend to create a SSIS package for this as the authentication will be easier to configure.

Can you please post the linked server configuration for further information?

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the query is using two servers, identified by IP address as shown below.  Where is the server [123.456.7.890]? And where is the server [098.765.4.321]?

My guess is that [098.765.4.321] is the [RemoteServer] and [123.456.7.890] is the [LocalServer].

First of all, the slowness of the code is not SQL Agent's fault.  Code run from SQL Agent is pretty much as efficient or inefficient as code run directly from SSMS. The problem is that you are moving much more data across the linked server than you might think.  Here is the outline of your code:

```
INSERT ... INTO [LocalServer].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE] 
   SELECT TOP 3 ... FROM [RemoteServer].[DBASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2]
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT ... FROM [LocalServer].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE])
```

If I have interpreted this correctly, then likely most of the data in `[RemoteServer].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]` has to be dragged over to the `[LocalServer]` and stored in a worktable in `tempdb`.

It is extremely unlikely that the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is processing to find the first 3 matching rows that come across the linked server. Instead it likely waits for the data to be present locally, before processing the worktable data to filtered by the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and then choose the `TOP 3` rows.

The slowness is due to how much data is being moved between servers and by the likelihood that the [LocalServer] does not have access to the [RemoteServer]'s statistics.

You might also read the **Guidelines for Using Distributed Queries** at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175129(v=sql.105).aspx   In part, the document says: "To create the best query plans ..., the query processor must have data distribution statistics from the linked server."

Using OPENQUERY to get the results from a remote server will often result in better performance.  When using OPENQUERY, the query is sent to the REMOTE server and is executed there in order to return data to the local server. (You will notice that in OPENQUERY the query uses a three-part name, since it runs directly on the remote server.)

Likewise, at times creating a stored procedure to run on [RemoteServer] would allow processing to happen on that server first, then return a more limited data set.  After that data is returned, the code on the [LocalServer] can complete the process.

Movement of data is costly to overall performance and moving data between servers is even more costly.